# How to break an animation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I've made a hover effect on list items. Whenever I hover over a list item, an anmiation happens which was done with `.animate()`. When I hover away from the list item, the hover animation is not being overwritten until it reaches its final point.

When leaving the list item with my cursor, what would be the best way to stop the list item from doing the hoverIn effect and make it do the hoverOut effect?

```js
var hoverInOptions = {
  'margin-left': '+=50px',
  'font-size': '+=2px',
}
var hoverOutOptions = {
  'margin-left': '-=50px',
  'font-size': '-=2px'
};


$('#menu li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).animate(hoverInOptions, 2000);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate(hoverOutOptions, 200);
  }
);
```

```css
#menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  border: 1px solid #309;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider jQuery's [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/).

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.
>   `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`

Since your animations are relative to the existing position (adding or subtracting margin), I've used `stop(true,true)` to clear the queue and jump to the end of the current animation.

```js
var hoverInOptions = {
  'margin-left': '+=50px',
  'font-size': '+=2px',
}
var hoverOutOptions = {
  'margin-left': '-=50px',
  'font-size': '-=2px'
};


$('#menu li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate(hoverInOptions, 200);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate(hoverOutOptions, 200);
  }
);
```

```css
#menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  border: 1px solid #309;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
</ul>
```

---

However, if you change your animations to fixed values, you can avoid jumping to the end of the animation; the next animation will continue from the position the last animation left off.

```js
var hoverInOptions = {
  'margin-left': '50px',
  'font-size': '1.2em',
}
var hoverOutOptions = {
  'margin-left': '10px',
  'font-size': '1em'
};


$('#menu li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate(hoverInOptions, 200);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate(hoverOutOptions, 200);
  }
);
```

```css
#menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  border: 1px solid #309;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
</ul>
```

---

Alternatively, you might consider CSS [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to perform the animations without JavaScript:

```css
#menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  border: 1px solid #309;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: margin .2s, font-size .2s;
}

#menu li:hover {
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
</ul>
```